# mysqld is not running. How do I start it?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm setting the mysqladmin passwords like so :

```
mysqladmin -u root -hec2-50-17-36-83.compute-3.amazonaws.com password my_password
```

And this returns :

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'ec2-50-17-36-83.compute-3.amazonaws.com' failed
error: 'Unknown MySQL server host 'ec2-50-17-36-83.compute-3.amazonaws.com' (1)'
Check that mysqld is running on ec2-50-17-36-83.compute-3.amazonaws.com and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet ec2-50-17-36-83.compute-3.amazonaws.com 3306'
```

How do I check that mysqld is running, and better yet, how do I fire her up?

Thanks!

**Thus so far:**

I logged into the remote DB server ( an EC2 instance ), and performed this :

```
vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

The option `skip-networking` was already commented out as well as the bind-address. So I uncommented the bind address, and added the IP of my remote server, and restarted mysqld.

That didn't work. So I tried the remote DB server. That didn't work.

On the remote DB server ( EC2 Instance ), the only command for mysqld you can perform is `mysqld` with no options. I'm just assuming this is actually appropriately resetting it when I write this because it hangs on the command for a few minutes before proceeding.

Running this `netstat -nl | grep :3306` on the remote DB server returns this :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Not sure if this is relevent, but /etc/init.d/mysqld does not exist on the remote DB server.
But the command does exist in /usr/sbin/mysqld .

Comment: Assuming that what you posted is the real name of the host you're trying to connect to, it doesn't resolve in DNS to any IP address. I don't know whether MySQL is running or not on the host, but you are not going to be able to connect to it by using this host name.
Can you try connecting by IP address?

Comment: I changed a couple numbers. Were you testing it? It seems to be running on the host because I can log into it directly with a mysql command and no password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has already said:

```
$ telnet ec2-50-17-36-83.compute-3.amazonaws.com 3306
```

If you cannot connect, make sure that the hostname can resolve to the right IP address:

```
$ nslookup ec2-50-17-36-83.compute-3.amazonaws.com
```

If it does, ssh to your server and start it if it hasn't been started:

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

It means that your MySQL server only listening to the localhost, disable the remote access. If you **really** want to allow, do the below steps:

- ssh to your server
- open the `/etc/my.cnf` file and change the `bind-address` to your
  public IP
- comment out the `skip-networking` option (put a `#` at the begin)
- restart mysqld: `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`
- grant access to the user: `grant all privileges on foo.* to
  'user'@'IP' identified by 'password';`

Comment: Ah great idea. Still getting used to a few new things here. But I was able to SSH into the remote server ( no password was required ). Then the only option I can run is `mysqld`. Then I did a `ps aux | grep mysqld`, looks like its running. Still the same error though when trying to set the passwords.

Comment: ssh to your server and post the output of `netstat -nl | grep :3306`?

Comment: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN `

Comment: I also tried to just connect to the IP instead of the host and I get a `timeout`.

Comment: This is what it says on the remote db server as well `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: wait, what? Is the previous output (`127.0.0.1:3306`) on your local?

Comment: I found the my.cnf in `/etc/mysql` and what you mention was already commented out.

Comment: Did you restart? What does `netstat -nl | grep :3306` say now?

Comment: On my remote DB server it also had commented out the bind address. Which i changed to the IP of my remote server. then I went to restart it, but EC2 only allows one command and that's `mysqld`. No options allowed. So I tried that, it hangs for awhile and then ran netstat. It returned this : `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: Haha..ugh..I figured it out. I can't thank you enough Quanta for being a HUGE help. I wish there was a way I could return the favor. Thank you.